# Reading I2C bus frequency from /proc/device-tree/i2c@XXXXX/clock-frequency

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

I am working on some userspace validation tool. In which I need to validate i2c freq.

In my DT file, I set `clock-frequency = <400000>;`, And I read it back from  `/proc/device-tree/i2c@XXXXX/clock-frequency` from userspace. But I am getting some garbage data.

Output:

```
root@mymachine:~# od -bc /proc/device-tree/i2c\@XXXXXX/clock-frequency                                                                        
0000000 000 006 032 200
         \0 006 032 200
0000004
```

Is it in compressed form? If yes, How can I decompress it?

Output of `file` command:

```
root@nvidia:/proc/device-tree# file i2c\@7000*/clock-frequency
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: TTComp archive data
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: raw G3 data, byte-padded
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: TTComp archive data
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: raw G3 data, byte-padded
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: TTComp archive data
i2c@7000XXXX/clock-frequency: TTComp archive data
```

Comment: What kernel and SoC are you using? On my am335x and kernel 3.15 I don't even see such an entry.

Comment: It's a DT enabled 3.10.49 on Nvidia tegra based SoC.

Answer (score 1):

It's not compressed, it's just a raw binary unsigned 32-bit int stored big-endian. The four bytes you have there are shown in octal: 0, 6, 32, 200, in decimal are 0, 6, 26, and 128, and as a 32-bit int is 6*65536 + 26*256 + 128 = 400000.

There are many ways to unpack that; from python, on my RPi 2, which currently has an i2c freq of 100000:

```
>>> import struct; struct.unpack(">I", open('/proc/device-tree/soc/i2c@7e205000/clock-frequency').read())
(100000,)
```

Comment: Sometimes on the embedded systems the Python is not available due to bloat.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find useful the following parameters for `od` that automatically swap the endianness and print in decimal format.

For example if bus speed is set to 100 KHz (tested on ARM 64 arch):

```
# od -td --endian=big /proc/device-tree/soc\@0/bus\@########/i2c\@########/clock-frequency
0000000      100000
0000004
```

The --endian option is available from coreutils 8.23: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/b370924c03adaef222859061c61be06fc30c9a3e.

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the output using the follow (note the parameters):

```sh
od -txz -Ax /proc/device-tree/i2c\@XXXXXX/clock-frequency
```

If your `clock-frequency` was set to 100kHz you should get something like this:

```auto
000000 a0860100
000004
```

And after swapping the endians, you should get `0x186a0` which is 100kHz in decimal.

Comment: Swapping bytes in shell can be done with help of `grep -o | tac`. Ex. https://gist.github.com/andy-shev/2c388310f2773ead647d9c1a3f1c813f#file-prepare-u-boot-sh-L33